# Enter key is detected even when it's not pressed

Tags: c#

Currently, I have this:

```
if ((input.Text.ToUpper() == "FURNACE" || input.Text.ToUpper() == "COAL") && count == 3)
                {
                    end3();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unknown key");
                }
```

However, no matter if I enter FURNACE, COAL, or anything else, it still pops up with "Unknown key". Why?

It's under a KeyUp event, like this:

```
private void input_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
        { 
          //The earlier code I showed goes here
        }
    }
```

Count varies, one of the if (input.Text.ToUpper...) is adding one to count, but it starts at zero.

Input is a textbox.

Comment: What is the type of `input` ? it is a textbox for example?

Comment: It (count) varies, one of the if (input.Text.ToUpper...) is adding one to count, but it starts at zero.

Comment: Yeah, it's a textbox. I added both of your questions to the answer, it'll probably help others.

Comment: `"no matter if I enter FURNACE, COAL, or anything else, it still pops up with Unknown key"`. This must mean that count does not equal 3. Put a breakpoint on the if statement and see the value of count in the locals window.

Comment: It does go up one before it's supposed to, but how do I have it not trigger the else? There's no way around it, I will have to add one to count after the first if. Also, there'll be a lot of ifs, so putting an if (input.Text != "whatever") won't work.

Comment: The logic of your code depends on the value in input.Text AND on the value of `count`. You should show the  code that changes the value of count.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aaDAMJFD <-- That's the code I used, I can't post code as a comment.

Comment: @chipperyman573 please put your complete code to get your probelm. We cannot figure what is it exactly

Comment: @Desolator I'm sorry, what's compile code? Is that everything I wrote?

Comment: @chipperyman573 sorry, I mean "complete" code

Comment: Oh, okay. http://pastebin.com/9e3tLxcS

Comment: @chipperyman573 so your problem is that Enter key is being detected although not pressed?

Comment: Your code is working for me. you need to double check your count variable, the only way it will become 1 in your code is if you type continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are missing `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;` right after you enter to the `if` so when you press enter it will not appear as char in your text.

```
private void input_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    { 
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        if ((input.Text.ToUpper() == "FURNACE" || input.Text.ToUpper() == "COAL") && count == 3)
        {
            end3();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unknown key");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i edited the answer. if this will not work do the same but on key down. i usually do this on key done and not key up.